# How can I write rising exponents in latex?

Tags: math-mode, equations, symbols

How can I write this expression in latex

[image: exponents]

Comment: Did you try `$a^{b^c}$`?

Answer (score 4):

`a^b^c` is intentionally a syntax error to force you to choose which of the following you mean:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$a=3, b=2, c=3$
\[
{a^b}^c = 9^3 = 729, 
a^{b^c} = 3^8 =6561
\]
\end{document}
```

Note in the first form c is a superscript (7pt) but in the second it is in scriptscript style (5pt)

Answer (score 3):

It's as simple as typing it out straight

```
a^{b^c}
```

[image]

Comment: or (depending on the intended meaning) `{a^b}^c`, you could show both

Comment: But this is only $a^{bc}$…

Answer (score 3):

I’m gonna take your question literally. `;-)`

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Hello, world.

\includegraphics{exponent.png}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Next challenge is to recreate the image completely with tikz

Comment: I also am expecting semantically meaningful translation to MathML from this input.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There are actually apps for that nowadays.

Comment: @Gaussler mathpix got close but did not recognise the b so produced `$a^c$`

Comment: Seeing this kind of joke here is so refreshing.